# Retrieving the selected row in a CListCtrl

Tags: c++, clistctrl

I have a `CListCtrl` in which there are 2 columns and multiple rows. I want to get the the index of the selected row. I am able to get the row when the user clicks on the first column but could not when clicked on the second column.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `m_ListCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);` after the creation of the control - usually in `OnInitDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, that we have a Dialog with one CListCtrl object defined in the RC file like this:

```
IDD_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 435, 273
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "A Dialog :)"
FONT 12, "Microsoft Sans Serif", 400, 0, 0xEE
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST_CONTROL,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER,5,138,350,86
END
```

Then the CListCtrl object IDC_LIST_CONTROL behaves as a LVS_REPORT, which means
that clicking on any of its column selects the whole row.

Then the selected row is retrieved like this:

int selectedRow = ((CListCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_CONTROL))->GetSelectionMark();